"org.ofono.MessageManager interface" missing in "org.ofono" service
I'm working with the "org.ofono.MessageManager" interface to detect the "MessageAdded" signal on a currently connected Bluetooth device. However, while introspecting the object path, I noticed that the "MessageManager" interface is not available in the "org.ofono" service.
Here's the command I used to introspect:
user@user:~$ busctl introspect org.ofono /hfp/org/bluez/hci0/dev_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx

The available interfaces on the device are:
org.ofono.CallVolume
org.ofono.Handsfree
org.ofono.Modem
org.ofono.NetworkRegistration
org.ofono.VoiceCallManager

I can see the call control interfaces (e.g., VoiceCallManager) but not the message control interface (MessageManager). I'm looking to capture the "MessageAdded" signal, but it seems the "MessageManager" interface is missing
Is there anything additional that needs to be configured or installed for the "org.ofono.MessageManager" interface to be available? Could it be related to the device, setup, or the version of oFono I'm using? Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

oFono only calls ofono_sms_register() if its modem driver determines that the modem has SMS storage, e.g. after successful AT+CNMI response for AT-based modems (and similar over QMI or MBIM etc). If the interface is missing, that implies the modem didn't advertise SMS capabilities.
